# Can a node have more than one shard in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am reading "Elasticsearch: The Definitive Guide" and I would like to confirm something.

When we create an index, it will be assigned to 5 shards by default (or we can use the "number_of_shards" setting).

But if I am using just one node (one server), will the index be spread into 5 shards in the same node? I guess what I am asking is - can a node have multiple shards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes a node can have multiple shards of one or more indices. You can verify it for yourself by executing the `GET _cat/shards?v` command. Read more about the command [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-shards.html). The problem with having a single node Elasticsearch cluster is that replica shards for indices will not be allocated (but primary shards will be) as it does not make sense to have both the primary and replica of the same shard on the same machine.

Comment: What is the use of having shards on the same node? There is no advantage of multi processing as everything is running on a single node.